# Adding date function in php title tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, datetime

I want to add date function in `<title>` tag in php. Is it possible? i tried this

```
$this->pass_meta_data['title'] = "Welcome to our website, <?php echo date("Y");?>";
```

BUT this is not working, please help.

Comment: I tried this $this->pass_meta_data['title'] = "Welcome to our website, <?php echo date("d/m/y"); ?> ";

Comment: `PHP tag inside PHP tag??`

Comment: `"Welcome to our website, ".date("d/m/y");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current date:

```
$this->pass_meta_data['title'] = "Welcome to our website, " . date("d/m/Y");
```

Comment: You wouldn't need the extra `time()` parameter as this will implicitly called when no second parameter is given on the `date()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use concatenation operater `.`(dot) to join date with string.

```
"Welcome to our website, ".date("d-m-Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, there is the `printf` function for outputting a formatted string. In your case, that would be something like this:

```
$this->pass_meta_data['title'] = printf("Welcome to our website, %s", date("d/m/y"))
```

You'll find more info in the [printf docs](http://php.net/printf)